# npm install socket.io hangs on node-gyp step

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io, npm, node-gyp

I wanted to install `socket.io` via `npm` to use it in my `node.js` application. So I just entered `npm install socket.io -g` into my terminal and let it run.

```
> ws@0.5.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

After the last log message the regular progress spinner appears but it stops spinning after some seconds and starts to hang (indefinitely).
I can't imagine why this happens. No error message, no unusual resource usage in `System Monitor`, no whatever.
Does anyone of you know what it could be or where I could look for the reason?

I'm using `Ubuntu 14.10` with `Node v0.12.2` and `npm v2.7.4`. Further I have `python 2.7.8` and `node-gyp 1.0.3` installed.

Comment: Anything in `builderror.log`? Also, do you have a particular reason to install that module globally (`-g`)?

Comment: Maybe you are not using root?

Comment: Same here but within a docker container, tried ubuntu and debian and same problem with both. I think there is a problem with postinstall hooks

Comment: Same here on Mac OS X. Looking at node_modules afterwards, though, it seems that everything was properly installed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my ubuntu 12.04. Turns out I didnt have node-gyp installed on my system. I installed it using 
**sudo npm install -g node-gyp**
and was then able to install socket.io succesfully. :)

Comment: I also thought that and installed node-gyp, but its still not working. Btw, I am using Mac.